# How to connect a row with another row in anoter table

Tags: php, mysql, database

What I'm trying to do is to connect a user's ID in table1 to connect with his username in table2. and than display his username on a page. To reduce redundancy.

Can anyone get me on my way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [SQL join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp), which is used to bind data together across tables would be appropriate for this situation.  The syntax would be something along the lines of:

```
select username
from table1
join table2
on table1.userId = table2.userId
```